# Is Kleisli a functor, applicative, or monad?

Tags: scala, scalaz, kleisli

This question is inspired by the feedback given to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521070/michael)

`Scalaz` provides a wrapper class `Kleisli[M[_], A, B]` for a function `A => M[B]`.

`Kleisli[M[_], A, B]` is a semigroup if `M[_]` is a semigroup. Suppose that `M[_]` is a functor. Is it correct that `Kleisli` is a functor too ? What if `M[_]` is an applicative or monad ?

Comment: Kleisli cannot be a functor or a monad, it has the wrong kind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fully unapplied `Kleisli` isn't much of anything—it has kind `(* -> *) -> * -> * -> *`, and I don't know of any meaningful type classes for that kind.

If you have a monad for a type constructor `F[_]`, though, then `Kleisli[F, ?, ?]` is an `Arrow` (which is a type class for things of kind `* -> * -> *`).

Similarly, if `F[_]` has a functor instance, then `Kleisli[F, A, ?]` has a functor instance for any specific `A`. In fact the same thing works for applicative functors and monads—have an instance of any of them for `F[_]` and you have an instance for `Kleisli[F, A, ?]` as well.

Lastly, if you have a semigroup (or monoid) for `F[B]`, then `Kleisli[F, A, B]` is a semigroup (or monoid) for any `A`.